# ANDROID NDK ERROR with OPENCV

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I am new to android programming. Certain situations lead me directly to a project with real time image processing. I am trying to use OPENCV library, but eclipse shows the following error:

```
18:15:30 **** Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle ****
"E:\\AND_NDK\\android-ndk-r10d\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-15 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Android NDK: LOCAL_MODULE definition in jni/Android.mk must not contain space    
E:/AND_NDK/android-ndk-r10d/build/core/build-shared-library.mk:23: *** Android NDK: Please correct error. Aborting    .  Stop.
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have spaces on `jni/Android.mk`, which seems to be incorrect. You should try removing those blank spaces.

You might want to take a look at the following question too: [installing android OpenCV unable to locate error while building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920486/installing-android-opencv-unable-to-locate-error-while-building)

Comment: @Milel Hi, I tried it... But it still show an error on the project but no files shows error!!! 
Android NDK: Please correct error.Aborting     Stop
What might be the reason??? I've Clean Built the project

Comment: "main cannot be resolved or is not a field"
How this error be solved?? I already tried importing "import com.example.packagename.R;". But no change..