# Error: Program "/NDK-build" not found in PATH

Tags: android, c++, opencv, ubuntu, android-ndk

I need help. I'm trying to install and configure `OpenCV 2.4.7 library` in my computer (Ubuntu 12.04). After run OpenCV samples appears those errors in my Console:

Cannot run program `"/NDK-build"`: Unknown reason

Error: Program `"/NDK-build"` not found in PATH=`[/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games]`

I've seen numerous tutorials and nothing worked. I ask you to be very specific since I am "new" programming and also because my mother tongue is not English (I have some difficulties). Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

Easiest Method which worked for me is.

Goto the **Project Properties** 
Click on **C/C++ Build** (An other list will open) 
Click on the **Environment** from the list 
Now click on **Add**

Here you have to Put 2 values 
Put Name as **NDKROOT** 
In Value put **PATH TO THE NDK FOLDER**

[image]

You are done :)

Comment: Much better than exporting the environment variable. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Same case happened with me (when my NDK location was already set), so changing to original Android Builder removed my problem for doing so simply go to project properties, C/C++ Build | Tool Chain Editor and select Android Builder as current builder.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have android-ndk installed? If yes, add path to `ndk-build` to your path. 
e.g:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/android-ndk/bin
```

Comment: Yes, I do. Is this the way to add the Build Command or create a path variable and put this as the value? If you can get step by step.. Thanks!

Comment: where to put this path in Appilcation.mk ya Android.mk

Answer (score 0):

Add the ndk-build to your path

Follow this guide 
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/android/9781849691529/setting-up-your-environment/ch01lvl1sec18

Comment: The link does not seem to work anymore

Answer (score 0):

this is a frequent issue with openCV for Android. It stems from having the incorrect build target, which creates an error within the library for the Video.java file. After getting that patched up, you can import sample projects. Although, after fixing that, you may not be able to see the C/C++ Build node under project preferences. There's a fix for that on the second link. However, if under project preferences you can see C/C++ Build, make sure the path reads: "***${NDKROOT}/ndk-build***" Finally, it will be looking for NDKROOT,which is undeclared. The third link will direct you on how to do this, it's very simple. ALSO, make sure if your on MAC or LINUX to remove the .cmd from the end of NDK-BUILD. Good Luck!

```
Video.java issue:
    http://answers.opencv.org/question/8266/opencv-library-244-on-eclipse-gives-error/ 
C++ Build/General Missing from Project Preferences:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953548/eclipse-missing-c-c-build-and-general-from-project-properties
Now, make sure you add NDK root to the build varialbles so you can find it:
    http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_build_var.htm`
```